# OnSubmit not accepting function return in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to submit a form via ajax and no matter what I do submit triggers a page reload in IE7 as per normal post function.

What I have tried

```
    // Example function / attempt 0
<script>
    function FunctionName() {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           blah: "blah"
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>

// attempt 1
<form onsubmit="return FunctionName()">
// attempt 2
<form onsubmit="FunctionName(); return false;">
// attempt 3
$("#form id").submit(FunctionName);
```

What I end up getting is a garbled input via ajax and a page refresh every time.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: Firebug lights up my ajax as red but does not actually give me any error codes

Comment: That could mean that the page is returning a 500 or 404 (or other) error.  I just wanted to make sure the `FunctionName` function was being called, and that confirms it is.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/a6WR5/

I think you just have to enclose the `return FunctionName()` inside a function. Look at the fiddle.

Also, you don't need the document ready call.

Comment: simply enclosing it in a function declares a function (doesn't run the function). I decided to run the function in-line after declaring it basically function NameD(){return FunctionName()};NameD; and still got the undesired page refresh

Answer (score 0):

There were too many things wrong with your code. Here is code that should work:

```
<script>
function Name() {

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/echo/html/"
    });
    return true;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="return Name()">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

For your convenience here too: http://jsfiddle.net/jasdeepkhalsa/YQN6K/5/

Comment: Its been updated since I last saw it. Now looks EXACTLY same as mine, bar the various attempts at the end. Hopefully this should now workout

Comment: return true doesn't seem to work either, also seems a bit counter intuitive

Comment: @ert3 How is `return true` counter intuitive? If you don't want the form to submit you use `return false`, if you want it to submit you use `return true`. You've not really provided enough information for your question to be answered properly. What is your form's `action`, and what is your form's `method`, `POST` or `GET`? Also what URL is your AJAX call to and using what method? You mentioned your code didn't work in IE7, did you test it on other browsers and did it work OK?